# Transforming $x^2y''+x(1-2x\tan x)y'-(x\tan x+k^2)y=0$ into Bessel's Equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a bonus question we were give in my DE2 class. No one could solve it. How would you go about choosing the right substitution to make this work?

$ x^2y''+x(1-2x\tan x)y'-(x\tan x+k^2)y=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(x^2y''+xy'-k^2y)\cos(x)-(2x^2y'+xy)\sin(x)=0$$
Hint : change of function : $u(x)=y(x)\cos(x)$

(This is suggested by the term $-k^2y\cos(x)$ because a term $-k^2u$ must be found in the Bessel equation ).